# Network Deploy Font Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, deployment, font

Is there an  easy way to network deploy fonts with Windows Server 2003 and a Windows XP client base?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Active Directory you could build an MSI for the fonts and deploy via GPO.

Comment: +1 - I've done that many times for the hundreds of fonts that get installed each year in the yearbook classroom at the high school I support.

Answer (score 1):

The easy, but hack way, to do this, is to add a copy command to the login script for everyone that needs the font.

Something along the lines of:

```
net use y: \\server032\fontshare
copy y:\arial.ttf C:\Windows\Fonts
net use /delete y:
```

Yeah, it's truly a hack way to do it, but it should work in theory.

Answer (score 0):

SMS/SCOM is your friend.